# Can every topological space be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space such that $card(X)=card(\mathbb{R})$. When is it true that there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ such that there exists a continuous injection 
$$f: X \to \mathbb{R}^n,$$
with $X \cong f(X)$? If we don't require that $f$ satisfy any conditions other than continuity and injectivity and $X \cong f(X)$, is this always true for any space $X$?

Comment: I edited the question to allow $n$ to be infinite. This would exclude that case right?

Comment: that edit does remove one challenge. Another challenge might be an indiscrete topology on a space with more than one point, or more generally any topology that is not metrizable.

Comment: @leibnewtz what is the 'canonic' topology in case $n=\infty$?

Comment: I'm more than a beginner to this, but I would assume so. There are subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfy properties that $\mathbb{R}^n$ does not.

Comment: What topology you want yo consider in the infinite case?

Comment: @user251257: the usual topology would be the product topology.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the product topology

Comment: @CarlMummert yeah, but is it $\mathbb R^\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb R^\mathbb R$ or ...?

Comment: My assumption is that the cardinality of $X$ is equal to that of the continuum

Comment: @user251257 I was thinking $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$

Comment: @user251257 The space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ is **much** larger than the set of all reals . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber so? $f$ only needs to be injective...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have accidentally stumbled into a question about metrizability

The question was edited to include $\mathbb{R}^\infty$, the product topology on countably many copies of the real line. This space has a subspace $[0,1]^\infty$, consisting of a product of countably many copies of the unit interval. That space is known as the Hilbert cube.

On one hand, every subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is metrizable. On the other hand, if we begin with a separable metric space, it can be embedded as a subspace of the Hilbert cube, and thus embedded as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^\infty$.

So there are only two obstacles to embedding in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$: the space must be separable (which limits the cardinality of the space) and the space must be metrizable.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any interesting simple examples of spaces that aren't metrizable?

Comment: @leibnewtz: Any non-Hausdorff space. The long line. The pointwise convergence topology on the dual space of $C^\infty_0(\Bbb R^n)$.

Comment: A two point space with the indiscrete topology is a simple example. There are less simple examples that are very important in other areas of math, however, such as Zariski topologies in algebraic geometry.

Comment: One should clarify the word "embedded" before accepting this answer.  The text of the question speaks only of a continuous injection.  It can certainly be possible to find a continuous injection (which is not an embedding) from a non-metrizable or a non-separable space into a separable metric space.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge, the question says a continuous injection such that $X \cong f(X)$. I take this to mean $X$ is homeomorphic onto it's image.

Comment: @Rise: Oh, I overlooked that.  Sorry.